# Why request to server requesting for assets don't go to the public index..?

Tags: php, server, resources, response

Suppose i am using laravel or any other framework. The thing is that any request to the server is going to go to a specific file in case of laravel is the **public index.php** file.

For Example

```
Route::get('posts' , 'PostController@index')
Route::get('\post\{post}\comments' , 'CommentController@index')
```

Both of these request are going to land on **public index.php** in case we are using laravel. But When a request from an html `<img src="www.yourdomain.com/storage/image.jpg" />` came it just to to the storage directory and pull the image out of it.

1. What i want to know is why the img request does not goes to **public index.php**
   in this case

One more thing i was taking a look at the php `GET` request to get a resource(images/files etc) from some other server using `file_get_contents('http/something/img.jpg')` but people are taking that in some cases accessing a file like this an be rejected due to some issues. What can cause the request to fail i don't get. And for what reason we create a stream context `stream_context_create` to read a file using `file_get_contents`

2. I totally understand about **Cross origin** but the point is if we are not requesting any script file. if we want to download an image. how can a image be protect by **cross origin** and if it is protected what will be the meaning of using `stream_content_create`

Please can someone give me some brief explanation about These two points.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. When your HTML file has a reference to an external file, for example `<img src="https://example.com/img.jpg">` The browser will fetch the requested image and render it to the view.
   There are some options for the `src="x"`

   - `src="image.jpg"`
   - `src="/image.jpg"`
   - `src="https://external-link.com/image.jpg`

To understand the differences between the 3 above search for `relative path` and `absolute path`.

2. Sometimes the HTTP server you are requesting from chooses to ignore requests coming from cross-site, which means, an HTTP server other than the one running the website.

Comment: i think you dont understand what i am asking for.. i edited the question.. take another look at it